# Almacenar x filas en una caja de texto textarea

Tags: php

Tengo un campo y quiero que me llene las filas que recibo de mi base de datos.

Este `value` solo me toma el primero, pero quiero que aparezca uno debajo de otro.

Éste es el código PHP:

```
  <label>PRODUCTO:</label>
  <?php 
  include "../conexion.php";
  $id_ped = $_REQUEST['id_ped'];
  /*Mi consulta*/
  $query = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT det.id_ped,pr.id_prod,pr.nom_prod,
                                          det.pref_prod,det.cant_prod 
                                   FROM det_ped det 
                                   INNER JOIN producto pr ON det.id_prod = pr.id_prod
                                   INNER JOIN pedido ped ON det.id_ped = ped.id_ped WHERE 
                                                            det.id_ped=$id_ped");
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
                            
  if ($count>0) {
    while ($datito = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  ?>
  /*Aquí mi caja de texto, donde muestro el nombre de mi producto*/  
  <input class="input_persona" name="id_prod" id="id_prod"
         value="<?php echo $datito['nom_prod']; ?>">
    
  <?php } } ?>
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que almacene x filas? ¿Para ti una caja de texto es un `<textarea>` o un `<input type="text">`?

Comment: Que me llene todas las filas(nombre de los productos), sería en un textarea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que deseas sería enviar el texto al navegador de la siguiente manera:

```
<label>PRODUCTO:</label>
<?php 
include "../conexion.php";

/*Mi consulta*/
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "
    SELECT det.id_ped, pr.id_prod, pr.nom_prod,
        det.pref_prod, det.cant_prod
    FROM det_ped det 
    INNER JOIN producto pr
        ON det.id_prod = pr.id_prod
    INNER JOIN pedido ped
        ON det.id_ped = ped.id_ped
    WHERE
        det.id_ped = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_REQUEST['id_ped']) ."'"
);

?><textarea><?php
while ($datito = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($datito['nom_prod']), PHP_EOL;
}
?></textarea>
```

Cambios a destacar:

- Si no usas consultas preparadas hay que usar, en su lugar, [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](https://php.net/es/mysqli_real_escape_string) para escapar el contenido de una variable que está fuera de tu control.
- Para enviar texto al documento HTML hay que usar [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://php.net/es/htmlspecialchars) para escapar los caracteres especiales HTML.